# Try successive methods until OK in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to create an object using different methods in a given order. My goal is to try these methods until I find one that returns something different than NULL.

```
$a = method_1();
if(!$a) $a = method_2();
if(!$a) $a = method_3();
...
if(!$a) print "Error";
```

Until then, I am doing this using imbricated if-else structures. Is there a more "elegant" way to program this ?

Comment: `foreach(['method_1', 'method_2'] as $callback) { if (!$a = $callback()) { break; } } if (!$a) { echo 'error'; }`